# Samsung smart TV Access point security key

Tags: tizen, television, samsung

How can I get the SoftAp security key from Samsung Smart TV in JavaScript?

I tried the code below:

```js
let password=null;
try {
  password = webapis.network.getSoftAPSecurityKey();
} catch (err) {
  
  console.log("error status: " + err.status);
  console.log("error name: " + err.name);
  console.log("error message: " + err.message);
}
```

but  I get the below error:

```
error status: undefined
error name: UnknownError 
error message: Failed to get Soft AP security Key
```

Notice that  I specified in the config xml:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.softAP"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
```

and in index.html I included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported on normal smart TV.
If you want to use this feature, please get in touch with a technical support member for you

Comment: Thanks, the device in witch a test the code is an Hôtel TV Model: HG50AU800EUXEN.